# Custom C++ library dependent on ARPACK wrapped in pybind11 segfaults when NumPy is also imported

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, pybind11, arpack

I am creating a custom library (written in C++) that does some numerical stuff with ARPACK-NG. The function is wrapped in pybind11 to provide access to the method from Python in a package. I observe strange behavior.

## Overview of the issue

### When NumPy is imported before my method is called, a segfault occurs.

```
import numpy as np
from mylib import mymethod

mymethod() # Segfault
```

The same also results if the import order changes.

```
from mylib import mymethod
import numpy as np

mymethod() # Segfault
```

### When NumPy is imported after my method is called, everything works fine.

```
from mylib import mymethod
mymethod() # Works fine

import numpy as np

# Further calls to NumPy or my library works also.
```

## GDB Trace

The backtrace looks like this.

```
#0  0x00007fffec59d2ef in mkl_blas.cdotc () from /home/myname/.conda/envs/mylib/lib/./libmkl_intel_lp64.so.1
#1  0x00007ffff7281974 in cneupd_ () from /home/myname/.conda/envs/mylib/lib/libarpack.so.2
#2  0x00007ffff72af228 in cneupd_c () from /home/myname/.conda/envs/mylib/lib/libarpack.so.2
#3  0x00007ffff76b25cd in void complex_symmetric_runner<float>(double const&) ()
   from /home/myname/Documents/mylib/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/mylib/libmylib.so
#4  0x00007ffff76b102b in mymethod() ()
```

## Replicable example

The test code is essentially the same as the [C++ example provided by ARPACK-NG](https://github.com/opencollab/arpack-ng/blob/master/TESTS/icb_arpack_cpp.cpp), with the main method replaced by `mymethod()`. The minimal binding code is

```
#include<pybind11/pybind11.h>

// ARPACK-NG C++ example code goes here. The main method is replaced with mymethod so it can be called from pybind11.

void mymethod(){
   // ...Contents of the main() function in the example ARPACK-NG code...
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(mylib, m){
    m.def("mymethod", mymethod);
}
```

## My guess at what the issue is.

I believe there is some issue with NumPy and MKL's initialization, similar to [this issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/15691). From what I've gathered, NumPy links to MKL through `mkl_rt` dynamically through `libmkl_rt.so`, as shown in the NumPy config below.

```
import numpy
numpy.show_config()
```

```
blas_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/myname/.conda/envs/mylib/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/myname/.conda/envs/mylib/include']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/myname/.conda/envs/mylib/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/myname/.conda/envs/mylib/include']
lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/myname/.conda/envs/mylib/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/myname/.conda/envs/mylib/include']
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/home/myname/.conda/envs/mylib/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/myname/.conda/envs/mylib/include']
Supported SIMD extensions in this NumPy install:
    baseline = SSE,SSE2,SSE3
    found = SSSE3,SSE41,POPCNT,SSE42,AVX,F16C,FMA3,AVX2
    not found = AVX512F,AVX512CD,AVX512_KNL,AVX512_KNM,AVX512_SKX,AVX512_CNL
```

My library links to it through ARPACK-NG's shared library dynamically, and per the GDB trace, ends up linking to `libmkl_intel_lp64.so`. This is confusing, however, because when I type `ldd /home/myname/.conda/envs/mylib/lib/libarpack.so.2` there is no mention of `libarpack.so` linking to MKL.

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000697945afd000)
libblas.so.3 => /home/myname/.conda/envs/mylib/lib/./libblas.so.3 (0x0000697945200000)
libgfortran.so.4 => /home/myname/.conda/envs/mylib/lib/./libgfortran.so.4 (0x0000697945972000)
libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00006979450db000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x0000697944ed1000)
libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x000069794596d000)
libquadmath.so.0 => /home/myname/.conda/envs/mylib/lib/./libquadmath.so.0 (0x0000697944e97000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /home/myname/.conda/envs/mylib/lib/./libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000697944e82000)
/usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000697945aff000)
```

If I were to guess what is happening, NumPy is checking to see if some BLAS library is loaded in when it is imported. If my code is called first, `libblas.so` is loaded in by it and NumPy happens to use that. However, if NumPy is imported first, it loads in MKL for the BLAS library, which somehow interferes with `libarpack.so`.

Is my assessment correct and is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: with the 5-tag limit, I swapped your [c++] for [anaconda], which may be highly-relevant and isn't implied by other tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, what I believed to be the root cause of the issue is correct. I have arrived at a solution that, while not completely satisfactory, nonetheless solves the problem: instantiate the Anaconda environment with the `nomkl` package (i.e. `conda create -n mylib_nomkl nomkl python=3.9 numpy`). NumPy will no longer try to swap out the BLAS out from under ARPACK-NG.